# Creating an update script from Oracle using TOAD

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

In Oracle, using TOAD, we are able to create an insert script from a table.

However, I need to create an UPDATE script based on the values of each row

```
where the CLIENTID is 'blah blah'
```

Originally, what I did was create an Excel spreadsheet with all the necessary data and for each row, I pasted a

```
UPDATE TABLE BLAH BLAH SET COLUMN1 = "xxx", COLUMN2 = '' where CLIENT_ID = "123'
```

..but I ran into some difficulties with exporting the spreadsheet into a text based DOS file and converting it to a `.sql` as so to edit but it was messy and unpredictable.

Has anyone have a better idea I can implement?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any feature in Toad that helps write update queries in this fashion. But loading data directly is something that Toad makes very easy.

May be you could do this.

```
create table tmp_excel_data
( column1 varchar2(100),
  column2 varchar2(100),
  client_id varchar2(100)
);
```

Use toad to directly load data into this table. The update is simple from this point.

```
update CLIENT_DATA tgt
  tgt.column1 = (select column1
                  from tmp_excel_data src
                  where tgt.client_id = src.client_id);

--dont forget to commit.
```

This will also let you cleanse your data (removing dups..for example) if needed.

Comment: Yeah..I was thinking along the lines of that but...I would have to send a  script that creates a temp table, imports data, updates the table then omits the temporary table and of course commit..all of that on a production server..like sending a probe to Mars and hoping it lands..:-) thanks so much for your response.

Comment: I hate input data in excel spreadsheets. Had it been some form of text file, you could do so many cool things (build external table and then do correlated update or automate the loading part). Not that you can't automate the spreadsheet conversion, but it is difficult to do all of that in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something like this:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> SET status =''' || status || '''  WHERE id =' || ID ||';'
FROM <TABLE_NAME>
WHERE <condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the button. Its ugly but it works.

[image]